# how to extract short date from a full date date string?

Tags: android, date

i am getting date from webservice

example:
Wed, 29 june 2011 07:13:33

now i dont want to show full date with time zone just **Wed, 29 june 2011**
any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was already solved on StackOverflow here: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)
(that is converting date string to java date)

Here is for your example:

```
String inDate="Wed, 29 june 2011 07:13:33";
    Date date;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(inDate);
        System.out.println(date); //Wed Jun 29 07:13:33 CEST 2011
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Printing out date itself should be the least of your problems

Comment: You get an actual date this way. How you will output it is your choice

Comment: [Try this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and look at the symbol chart (mainly 'E')

Comment: after converting it to date now i can mention my required format to get appropriate date format. thanks.

Comment: The OP asked how to get a Date value to a string in the specified format. This answer is the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: @johnw182 in order to display in different format you must first parse it to be able to display it. Displaying parsed date is not a problem, that's why it's accepted

Answer (score 4):

```
try{
      SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E ,dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss");   
      SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd-MM-yyyy");    
      Date date = format1.parse(dateStr);     
      System.out.println(format2.format(date));  
 }
 catch(exception e){}
```