# Date format conversion problem

Tags: android, simpledateformat

Am having problem in using simple date format for this: having date as

```
12/13/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

For that am using:

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

but throwing an exception while coversion saying:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 12/13/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662673/how-to-extract-short-date-from-a-full-date-date-string/6662731#6662731)

Comment: basically you forgot about the "AM" part in parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using `HH:mm:ss`

However, according to the [Android Dev Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `HH` is for 24 hour clock.

use `h` or `K` or `k` depending your requirements instead.

Don't forget the am/pm marker as well which is denoted by `a`

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Convert Date from dd/mm/yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy

```
if (date.matches("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}")) {
    SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    parsedDate = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(date));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
```